# How can you flag which OBJECTS in an ngFor loop are 'dirty'?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following code to put a list of objects onto the page:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let setting of settings; let i = index;">
            <td>{{setting.section}}</td>
            <td>{{getTenantName(setting.tenant)}}</td>
            <td>{{setting.name}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="!setting.restWritable">
              <span>{{setting.value}}</span>
            </td>
        <td *ngIf="setting.restWritable && !setting.secret">
          <input class="form-control" [name]="'Value' + i" [(ngModel)]="setting.value" />
        </td>
      </tr>
```

And I have a requirement that only the DIRTY / edited / changed objects are sent back to the server..  (aka the input has been changed by the user)

I also understand that I can use the forms to find out if a single input is dirty, but I was hoping there was a way to do this at the OBJECT level.
so in other words, if any of the fields in that object are dirty the entire object is dirty and should be returned to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @ViewChild to access the form object in the component or better solution is to go for reactive forms where you will have access to the entire form. And you need to have the form control names different to have different controls in the form object

html:

template:

@ViewChild('someForm') myForm: NgForm
now you will have access to myForm.dirty

For a small example I have forked the angular template driven forms:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fu35pz-vlr7bm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-form%2Fhero-form.component.html

Comment: This is good stuff, I think this is half of the battle.  I think the problem remains that I have to send a list of settings[] to the server..  and I still only have a list of controls with a dirty flag, with no real direct relation....  I was hoping there would be a way to almost MAP the dirty flag to the setting object?

Comment: If you really want to use the form as a model, better to go for a reactive form, create a form array with various controls from the settings array, then you will have the form model value in the component and you can just get the dirty settings using settingsFormGroup.controls.filter(control => control.isDirty).value.

Comment: could you add a code sample, that sounds like that i am looking for! @Kaushik

Answer (score 1):

If you generating form controls by ngFor directive you are using template-driven form.

Add `#form="ngForm"` to your `form` tag. Then by `@ViewChild() form: NgForm` you can get reference to your form. Then you can list all your fields and filter them by specific attribute.

The only trick is you have to generate unique id and name for every control in template.

Comment: This is good stuff, I think this is half of the battle.  I think the problem remains that I have to send a list of settings[] to the server..  and I still only have a list of controls with a dirty flag, with no real direct relation....  I was hoping there would be a way to almost MAP the dirty flag to the setting object?

Comment: @JBoothUA Unfortunately I do not know solution for your problem. I suppose there is no automatically solution in Angular to achieve this.